# What is the efficient way of printing the status of a loop when the iterations are in millions

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I am reading a file (containing 800 million lines) line by line and then processing the data (very light processing, basically formatting the strings) and then writing the processed line into another file.

If I want to print a statement for every 1 million rows read from the file, a basic way is to add a if statement checking the iteration variable and for every % million == 0, I print the statement.

Now, this code checks in every iteration if the index has reached the next million and this is additional processing in every iteration right?

Is there any other efficient way to do this so that only when the iteration index variable reaches multiples of million, there is some signal sent and the statement gets printed?

Comment: No, you are fine. Have you measured and found this check to be a bottleneck?

Comment: Minioptimalisation. Compare this with one thread processing to a queue and one thread writing the queue to the file. (In your case the queue overhead would be too much, likely.) What about a timer that after every second writes the progress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, this code checks in every iteration if the index has reached the next million and this is additional processing in every iteration right?

Correct

> Is there any other efficient way to do this so that only when the iteration index variable reaches multiples of million, there is some signal sent and the statement gets printed?

No there isn't<sup>1</sup>.

But don't worry that this is "inefficient".  The cost of the tests is most likely *2 or more orders of magnitude* less than the cost of reading and processing the data.

<sup>1 - On reflection, in some circumstances it might be more efficient to decrement a dedicated counter, and test to see if it is zero.  Also, the '%' approach won't work properly if the counter overflows.</sup>

---

General piece of advice.  Don't spend time "optimizing" things at this level unless you have **evidence** that you have a bottleneck.  You need to profile your application with *real* data so that you can decide whether it is worthwhile optimizing this aspect of your application.

Answer (score 3):

On my machine, the following takes 1.4 seconds:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 800000000; ++i) {
        if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
            System.out.print('.');
        }
    }
```

This indicates that you'll be fine. However, if in doubt, profile.

Answer (score 1):

If you are want a linear solution, it's impossible an optimal way as *Stephen C* said,

But there is an optimal solution when we talk about Parallelism,

If your iterative process state can be accessed by another Thread which is working on another processor for example, then it can tell you about its status at given points of time without Interrupting your iterative process,

It is also *optimal* because Printing the Status cost your iterative process **Θ(0)**, since it's done by external Thread over parallel processing-flow\processor

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you have 800M Lines of Text Data , needs to be processed and then copied into a single TextFile

- I would prefer a Public Parameter "NotifyAfter" which in your case is
  1M .
- Then if required I can break 800M lines to Batches of {NotifyAfter}
  and store them in a Array or Queue with {Start,End} .
- Now i Can spawn some threads , I have to be careful about
  Race/Deadlock here since they all read from same file.
- Each Sub Process will then complete it's work and Raise An Event -
  TaskComplete (Increment the no.s of Lines processed)

  - Here you have to decide - whether your threads writes everything to
    smaller files and then you stich them toghether
  - OR you can synchronize the code to write into same file.

I agree with Stephen - do not optimize , unless there is a evidence of bottle neck

Hope this helps !!